# node [file.js] produce different result with run browser, and nodejs .editor

Tags: node.js, command-line

I have below piece of code in test.js file

```
   function foo(){
      console.log(this.bar);
    }

    var bar = "bar1";
    var obj = {bar: "bar2"};

    foo();
    foo.call(obj);
```

when I run by 'node test.js',  I got result

```
undefined 
bar2
```

when I run in node .editor,   I got result

```
bar1 
bar2
```

I think the second result is right, but what is wrong with the first way? cuz I always do the first way.

what are the differences between them?

Comment: What did you meant by `node .editor`, is it REPL mode?

Comment: yes, in REPL, type '.editor'

Comment: Here is your answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967530/about-global-variables-in-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms when you run the your code using `node test.js`, Node JS will `require('test.js')` to run it. But when you are using the REPL mode, code you enter will execute directly in the REPL.

When using `require`, the variables on your `test.js` won't bind as global variables. So cannot access like `this.bar`

Answer (score 0):

I think when using 'node test.js',  node create a wrapper for test.js code, so there is no global variable bar.

while in .edit way, there is a variable bar defined in global scope.