# Why "delete this.x" not work on this object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging, javascript-objects

On running this code
why x is no getting delete from this global object
is delete operation not work on this(global) object?

```js
var x = 1;
console.log(this.hasOwnProperty("x")); // browser -> true
delete this.x; // -> x should be removed from this/window object

console.log(x);
```

Help me to understand this

Comment: `delete this.x` has an effect if you delete the `var` before `x = 1`.

Comment: How exactly are you running this in nodejs? Most likely, [`this` is not the global object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22770299/1048572) there - or at least [`var x` is not declaring a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967530/about-global-variables-in-node-js).

Comment: What is the point of `val` and that IIFE? Why not just `console.log(x)`?

Comment: @GrafiCode So? `this.x` is a property.

Comment: @GrafiCode No, `this.x` is referring to a property on the `this` value, which is an object here. Btw, the term "VariableObject" [is no longer used since 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40544709/1048572)

Comment: @GrafiCode That question and answer is specific to modules, not regular top-level code.

Comment: "*why x is no getting delete from this global object*" - because you declared a `var`, which creates a non-configurable (writable, but not deletable) property. Use strict mode to get an exception from the `delete`, or look at the return value of the `delete` expression which is false. Use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, 'x')` to see how the property is defined.

Comment: …and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596782/how-can-i-unset-a-javascript-variable for more explanation, as well as how to create a global property that can be deleted successfully